# Create a tar archive of the current directory without preceding period

Tags: tar

When I do the following:

```
tar czvf ../myarchive.tar.gz ./
```

I get a single (annoying) root folder in my tar archive:

[image: annoying]

How do I remove this awful period when creating the archive?

Comment: [This Stack Overflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9776491/1114687) might help you.

Comment: Or use `--transform`/`--xform`, as suggested by [Magnus](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19692619/1114687): `tar -cf /path/to/output.tar -C /path/to/input-directory . --xform='s!^\./!!'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't.

```
name=${PWD##*/}
cd ..
tar czf "$name.tar.gz" "$name"
```

(Note: this doesn't work if your shell has current directory symbolic link tracking turned on and the current directory is accessed via a symbolic link.)

Yes, this isn't what you asked, but this is what you should do. Archives that expand a lot of files in the current directory are annoying: it puts the burden of creating a target directory for the file on each person who unpacks the archive, and if they accidentally unpack them in a non-empty directory, it's hard to clean up. Most of the time, an archive should create a single toplevel directory whose name is the base name of the archive.

Comment: Understood. If I recall correctly, it's just really annoying to have to do an extra step to untar an archive into a specific directory (eg `tar xzvf archive.tar.gz && mv archive/* /output` vs. `unzip archive.zip -d /output`)

Answer (score 16):

The dot appears because `tar` creates the path structure the way you give in the arguments. So as you have given **.** as the source, the archive also is created in the same structure.

You can try this (*note: this won't match hidden files*):

```
tar -czvf ../myarchive.tar.gz *
```

**Updating with information from the n.st's comment and zhoux's answer**

```
tar --xform s:'^./':: -czvf ../myarchive.tar.gz ./
```

Comment: The `*` glob won't match hidden files.

Comment: :D  eh..just a beginer..didnt realize.

Comment: You could use some more bash globs to include hidden files — have a look [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9776491/1114687).

Answer (score 2):

better add ^ before the preceding .

```
tar --xform s:'^./':: -czvf ../myarchive.tar.gz ./
```

OR, all "/" in the full pathname inside the archive will be removed unless "/" is the end of the full pathname.

Comment: Please suggest an edit to that answer instead of posting a separate answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/144094/edit